# Git - folder after changing branch

Tags: macos, git, branch, finder

why are some folders(which are not in the repo) are still in my project-folder when I change the branch?

I already tried "git clean" but the folder are still there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git [doesn't track folders](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) by itself, hence it will not clean them either.

This situation often happens to me when some folder's contents is added to `.gitignore` in one branch, but when you switch to another branch that doesn't have them ignored, you will still get the content but this time showing up in the `git status`.

I would not bother with the empty directories like this unless they impede you in some way.